# can't find an IP address of my guest os (Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS) on Windows 10 (host) running VirtualBox 6.1.26

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I can't find an IP address of a guest OS (Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS) on Windows 10 (host) running VirtualBox (Version 6.1.26).

This is the view when I have only Adapter 1 configured and attached to "NAT"

[image]
[image]

As you can see there are 2 network interfaces.

This is the view when I add one more adapter attached to "Host-Only Adapter"

[image]
[image]

So now I have another network interface "enp0s8" but it doesn't have an IP address so I can't connect to it.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `Host-only Adapter` is exactly what it means.  It can only be used for that VM instance and nothing else.  It will not get any IP addresses assigned to it.  What do you mean by you can't find an IP address of your Guest OS?  I see it there assigned by NAT at 10.0.2.15.  If you want it to work with your complete network meaning Windows and the rest of your network you would setup a bridged adapter.

Comment: But I should be able to connect to it from host and I can't. I need an IP address.

Comment: This link should be able to help you out.  https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet

Comment: @Terrance thank you buddy